# array index out of bounds in counting for "true" boolean values in java

Tags: java, for-loop, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception

Please help. I'm having an indexArrayOutOfBounds in my code. what's wrong with this?
the compiler says the error occurs at the if ststement.

```
private void tableTest(){
        int nRow = sampleTable.getRowCount();
        int nCol = sampleTable.getColumnCount();
        int counter = 0;
        int j, i;

        Object[][] tableData = new Object[nRow][nCol];
        for (i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++){
            for (j = 3 ; j < nCol ; j++){
                tableData[i][j] = sampleTable.getValueAt(i,j);
                System.out.println(tableData[i][j]);
                //if(counter)
                //    Arrays.deepToString(tableData[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("end");
            if(tableData[i][j].equals(true)){
                counter++;
                System.out.print(counter);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: @HunterMcMillen There's only one.

Comment: Quick note for future reference - the *compiler* isn't saying where the error is at all, as an exception isn't a compile-time problem. It's important to be very clear about the difference between compile-time errors and execution-time errors.

Comment: @DavidWallace Actually there are two, one is commented out. I don't which one is being referred to.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen - In my experience, commented out code doesn't throw exceptions.

Comment: Cute. Who knows if this is actually the code being run. I was asking to clarify.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen this is actually the code being run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  need that `if` block to be inside the inner `for` loop, or the indexes don't match to anything in the array.

Currently, that `if` statement runs when `j` has already reached `nCol`, which means it has exceeded the bounds of the array.

To fix this, remove the `}` from the line below the comments, and add a `}` right at the end.  This effectively moves the `if` block up into the inner loop.

**Update**

You might get a null pointer exception calling `equals` on references in the array that have not been assigned an object.  You should probably change the `if` condition to say this.

```
if(tableData[i][j] != null && tableData[i][j].equals(true)){
```

Comment: A better fix would be to declare `i` and `j` within the relevant loops, at which point the current code would fail to *compile*.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast reply. :) i've done what you said but now, a NullPointerException occurs. what should i do about this?

Comment: I'm sorry. The NullPOinterException occurs at the if statement "if(tableData[i][j].equals(true))".

Comment: OMG. Thank you very muuuch! @david Wallace

Answer (score 2):

Once your inner loop :`for (j = 3 ; j < nCol ; j++){}`  terminates, the value of `j = nCol`. When you try to access element `tableData[i][j]` in your `if` condition, you are trying to reach to a memory location out of the bounds of the array.